# Apache DirectoryIndex not working for subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directoryindex

I'm using an .htaccess file to set a few options for a folder but the DirectoryIndex rule doesn't seem to be working in a sub-folder.  Here is my .htaccess file.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Folder"
Require user joe
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html
```

I know it is loading the .htaccess file because it is asking for the password if I try to go directly to the sub-folder but it won't load the index.htm file that is in there, I have to manually type in index.htm.  The root folder with the .htaccess file does automatically load the index.htm file.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: When you go to your subfolder, are you going to `http://example.com/subfolder` or `http://example.com/subfolder/` (trailing slash)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Passenger was causing the problem.  The solution was to disable Passenger for that folder.

```
<Location /public>
    PassengerEnabled off
</Location>
```